# problem show text (from name files) inside ruby shoes

Tags: ruby, shoes

first..sorry for my poor english and my big noob question..the problem is...

I need create a little shoes app than show the excel files inside a folder (this is only a part)...I define a method like this:

```
def show_proov
  files = Dir.new(personal_folder).entries
  xlsxfiles = files.find_all {|file| file.include?('.xlsx') }.map do |file| file.scan(/^\w+/) end
end
```

if I show in a alert it..it works and shows the files...so far so good:
now..the problem is than I wish iterate over this names and create a menu..when I try it I get a error related about "bad encode" (sorry but I've tried recreate this code but I never get this message again)

well..no problem...maybe a list_box could do the work:

inside my shoes app I define list_box :items => show_proov
doing that..nothing is render inside the windows...don't show anything

the same happen if I use

```
@items=show_proov
#@items.class = array
list_box :items => @items
```

it hasn't much sense but I must has the try...

thanks for read and for help!! :D

Comment: Could you show us `@items.inspect`?  I think it will not be what you want; it will be an array of arrays of strings.  What's the purpose of calling `scan`?  I think it will just chop off parts of your filenames if they have spaces in them.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that your show_proov function is returning an array of arrays.

```
[["file1"], ["file2"], ["file3"]]
```

This is because [String.scan](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001181) returns an array. Try adding .first, like so:

```
  xlsxfiles = files.find_all {|file| file.include?('.xlsx') }.map do |file| file.scan(/^\w+/).first end
```

Then the result will be:

```
["file1", "file2", "file3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you get somethinbg from excel the encoding is different, so use

```
.force_encoding("UTF-8")
```

on the string you get from ecel before manipulating it.
Cheers